# What are the authentic verses and source of Shri Hanuman Chalisa?

Tags: scripture, hanuman, hanuman-chalisa, tulsidas

Many people chant Hanuman Chalisa, which was written in Awadhi language by Shri Goswami Tulasidas like it given [here](https://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/chalisa/lord-hanuman/shree-hanuman-chalisa.html?lang=hi&ck=1).

But recently many people have started saying this is not the authentic version, and there are some mistakes in current version. [Here](https://www.instagram.com/reel/CqoEnX6raPb) you can see Shri Jagadguru Ramanandacharya Swami, giving some alternative verses. (Ref: [Book](https://jagadgururambhadracharya.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Mahaviri_Hindi_2021.pdf))

Current Verses:

1. शंकर सुवन केसरीनन्दन।
2. सब पर राम तपस्वी राजा।
3. सदा रहो रघुपति के दासा॥
4. जो शत बार पाठ कर कोई।

Alternatives suggested:

1. शंकर स्वयं केसरी नंदन।
2. सब पर राम राजसिर ताजा।
3. सादर हो रघुपति के दासा॥
4. यह सत बार पाठ कर जोई।

---

1. Is this authentic? What exactly does it say in the original scriptire or Mool Paat of Shri Hanuman Chalisa?
2. Where can we find the Mool Paat of Shri Hanuman Chalisa?

Answer (score 0):

Check Hanuman gadhi ayodhya. There you can have original hanuman chalisa